# How do I write information from classes into lists in typescript?

Tags: list, typescript

How do I write informations from classes into lists in typescript?

```
class UserDeposit {
username: string;
userdeposit: number;

constructor(username: string, userdeposit: number) {
    this.username = username;
    this.userdeposit = userdeposit;
}

getUsername(): string {
     return this.username;
}

getDepositValue(): number {
   return this.userdeposit;
}
}
```

I want to create a list, where I want to store all the information like this:

```
let deposit: UserDeposit[] = [
{ "username": "Test", "deposit": 20 },
{ "username": "Test2", "deposit": 20 },
..........., 
];
```

In my console output I want to get the number of players and the total value of deposit like this (pseudo code):

```
deposit.countUser + " User joined the Jackpot. The total value is " + deposit.totalValue 
2 User joined the Jackpot. The total value is 40$
```

I am a newbie with TypeScript.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is fine.

In this way you can add new elements to your list:

```
// initialize list:
let deposit: UserDeposit[] = [];

// add new elements
deposit.push(new UserDeposit('test1', 10));
deposit.push(new UserDeposit('test2', 20));
deposit.push(new UserDeposit('test3', 30));
```

And here comes the output:

```
console.log('Users: ' + deposit.length + '\nTotal Deposit Value: ' + deposit.reduce((a, b) => a + b.getDepositValue(), 0));
```

The console should print:

> Users: 3
>
> Total Deposit Value: 60

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for.